# How to create multiple Trello cards using API?

Tags: python, trello

Is it possible to create multiple Trello cards using only one API call? I'm looking for some kind of batch request.

There is a https://trello.com/docs/api/batch/index.html but it has a parameter:  list of *API v1 **GET** routes*. I use a **POST** request to create a card.

I currently use `POST /1/cards` from https://trello.com/docs/api/card/index.html in a loop, but it's extremely slow.

Comment: You can do so without using the API by copping a multiple lines string into the card it self and trello will ask you to create a single card or multiple in that given list, hope this helps

Comment: @JorgeVicenteMendoza Unfortunately the question is about doing it using the API, I can't do it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no way to create multiple cards through a single API call.  You should be able to make multiple calls in parallel (although keep in mind that you will be rate-limited if you abuse this).